# Limits and subsucesions

Tags: calculus, limits

If you are working with a monotonous function, it is possible to calculate a limit using a subsucesion, but if you get the same limit independently the subsucesion you use, can I claim that it is the limit of the function?

Comment: Yes, if a monotonic sequence has an infinite subsequence which converges to a limit then the original sequence must also converge to that same limit.  If this hasn't been proven to you already, then I encourage you to try to prove this fact yourself.

Comment: But if this sequence converges independently the subsequence you use, the sequence converges to this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function has a limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a,$$ then for every sequence $x_n\to\infty$ it is true that $$f(x_n)\to a.$$ It is not true the other way around (choose $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $x_n=\pi n$).

If a sequence converges, then so does every subsequence. If a subsequence converges, then the sequence does not converge in general (choose $a_n=(-1)^n$ and the subsequence $a_{2n}$).

Comment: "*If a subsequence converges, then the sequence does not converge in general*"  Correct, however with the additional assumption that the sequence is monotonic (*which was included in the original question*) then a subsequence converging *is* enough to assert that the sequence must converge as well.

Comment: Right, thank you :)

Comment: I agree, but what happens when you get the same limit with any subsequence? I mean, I know that if you get a limit whit a certain subsequence the function does not usualy converge to this limit, but if it does whith any subsequence?

Comment: It has to be true for every _sequence_ that converges to the point where you calculate your limit; this has nothing to do with subsequences, in this case.